# AWS - Kswapd0 is high CPU even when plenty of RAM available on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

This is driving me nuts and I can't find answers via google.

Even though I have plenty of ram free and no swap seems to being used, kswap0 is taking 90+ cpu.

Config:

```
Amazon EC2 nano server with 512mb ram
Running Ubuntu 1604+Nginx+php-fpm and 1 website
1gb swap
180mb of ram free
```

In sysctl.conf:

```
vm.swappiness = 0
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

Top screen shot sorted by cpu:
[image]

Top screen shot sorted by memory:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: For now I ended up using Ubuntu 14.04, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but AWS still have same problems on t type instances.

You can check swapiness value with this code

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Mine was 60. It means after %60 of my memory use swap is kicking in.
You can change this with a higher value or with "0" for disabling it.

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=90
```

This will be reverted after a reboot. So we need to edit "/etc/sysctl.conf" file for a persistent solution. First open the file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now find the this line and edit it as you wish:

```
vm.swappiness=1
```

Save the file and close it. That's all.

While your t type instances doesn't have enough space for swapping, disabling it make sense. I have same problem and disabling solved my problem for now.

Other option is upgrading your instance type.

Comment: Note that this configuration is not persistent, so it will revert after a reboot.

Comment: You are right. I've editted my answer for the persistent solution.